# Issue with permalinks for custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, permalinks, htaccess, front-end

I have a little issue here...

When i'm using default permalinks, everything works great, but when I set up

> %postname%

permalink in settings, my template with custom post type is not loaded. Instead of that it loads archive.php. On other site is works. In this site with the template that I use the custom post type, I have a front end post editing system and I'm using a plugin [User Submitted posts](https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-submitted-posts/). This plugin doesn't have support for custom post types, so I made a little change in code

```
$postData['post_type']  = 'link'; // here we add a custom field to array $postData
```

That works well with the post type. I've read about it [here](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/custom-post-type-26), so I used it and after that I've used the classic query for post types in my template.

I've no idea why the pretty permalink does not work for that site. Anny suggestions to why it is not working?

Comment: Is your custom post type `link` correctly registered, either using code (i.e. `register_post_type()`) or with a plugin like [Custom Post Type UI](https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-ui/)?

Comment: yes i'm using normal hook at functions.php